If $G$ is a group with each nontrivial element having an infinite order, does $\mathbb{Z}[\mathbb{G}] \cong 0$?
The definition of group ring in Wikipedia is

Let  be a group, written multiplicatively, and let  be a ring. The group ring of  over , which we will denote by [], or simply  is the set of mappings :→ of finite support (()is nonzero for only finitely many elements ), ...

Is the following proof concerning $\mathbb{Z}[G]$, where $G$ is a group in the title:
Let $f: G \to \mathbb{Z}$ be a nontrivial homomorphism with finite support and let $g \in supp(f)$, and let $f(g)=a$.
Since $g$ has infinite order, $g^n \in G$ for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, $f(g^n)=nf(g)=na$.
Since all nontrivial elements of $\mathbb{Z}$ are infinite order, $na\neq0$ for all $n$, and hence $g^n\in supp(f)$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$, which contradicts with the assumption of $f$ having finite support. Therefore, there is no nontrivial homomorphism of finite support $G\to \mathbb{Z}$, and hence $\mathbb{Z}[G]\cong 0$

It's equivalent, but you might find it easier to think of the group ring ZG as the free abelian group on G with multiplication arising from the multiplication on G in the natural way.

The definition of a group ring does not mean homomorphisms when talking about mappings, but rather maps of sets.

I see. Therefore the properties of homomorphism are irrelevant.

Yup. As an $R$-module, the group ring can be thought of as the free $R$-module on a (formal) basis $G$. In particular, for a nonzero ring, it is always nontrivial (even for the trivial group)

Thank you very much. That was very helpful.
